# I get Invalid From Body error in Discord js

Tags: discord.js

The bot's codes are TypeScript:
Code:

import { TextChannel } from "discord.js";
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";

export default{
category: 'Configuration',
description:'Sends a dropdown roles menu',

```
permissions:['ADMINISTRATOR'],

minArgs: 2,

expectedArgs: '<channel><text>',
expectedArgsTypes:['CHANNEL','STRING'],

slash:'both',

callback: ({message,args,interaction}) => {
    const channel = (message ?message.mentions.channels.first() : interaction.options.getChannel('channel'))as TextChannel
    if(!channel || channel.type != 'GUILD_TEXT'){
        return'Please tag a text channel'
    }
    args.shift()
    const text = args.join(' ')
    channel.send(text)

    if(interaction){
        interaction.reply({
            content:'Send a message',
            ephemeral:true,
            
        })
    }

}
```

}as ICommand

error screenshot: https://www.hizliresim.com/cqc6ir9

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `wok-commands` [documentation](https://docs.wornoffkeys.com/commands/correct-argument-usage), I am pretty sure `expectedArgs` require a space between them. Currently, your code has:

```js
expectedArgs: '<channel><text>'
```

It should be:

```js
expectedArgs: '<channel> <text>'
```

The error you are getting is probably because, without that space, `wok-commands` incorrectly parses your argument. When trying to ascertain what your arguments are, the template is something like this: `<{arg name}>`, where the contents inside the curly braces are the name of the argument. If you are doing `<channel><text>`, this follows the pattern like so: `<{channel><text}>`. This means `wok-commands` interprets your expected args as just one argument with name `channel><text`. Discord does not allow the `>` or `<` symbols in argument names, so this causes your error (as you can see from the error, the error says there is an issue with `options[0].name`, i.e. the name of your first argument).